# How to make criteria with array field in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, criteria

I'm using `Hibernate` and `Postgres` and defined a `character(1)[]` column type.

So I don´t know how to make this `criteria` to find a value in the array.

Like this query

```
SELECT * FROM cpfbloqueado WHERE bloqueados @> ARRAY['V']::character[]
```

Comment: did u check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649964/how-to-save-or-retrieve-an-array-column-using-hibernate

Comment: If you look the last answer, it's mine.

Comment: Can you place the source code which you have tried?

Comment: I don´t have a code because I only know how to make it with sql

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with `Postgres` and its types but you can define your own type using [custom basic type mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom). That could simplify the query.

There are many threads here on SO regarding Postres array types and Hibernate, for instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate). Another array mapping example that could be useful [is here](https://madhavivaram.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/mapping-array-column-of-postgres-in-hibernate/). At last, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630445/hibernate-doesnt-support-accessing-fields-on-usertypes-for-projection-criterias) of using Criteria with user type.

Code example could be

```
   List result = session.createCriteria(Cpfbloqueado.class)
   .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("characterColumn.attribute"), PostgresCharArrayType.class)
   )
   .setResultTransformer(Transformer.aliasToBean(Cpfbloqueado.class))
   .add(...) // add where restrictions here 
   .list()
```

Also, if it is not important for the implementation, you can define max length in the entity model, annotating your field with `@Column(length = 1)`.

Or if you need to store an array of characters with length of `1` it is possible to use a [collection type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-array).

---

I hope I got the point right, however, it would be nice if the problem domain was better described.

Comment: As I said in the topic, I want to find a value in the array, as IN clause, imagine, if a I have a array ´{'A', 'B', 'C'}´ and want to know if is possible to find this column look by 'B' value

Comment: @DiegoMacario: yes, it is possible using either ElementCollection and define the array field in the Hibernate entity model (and query it like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090364/hql-how-to-query-elementcollection-of-string) or defining your own array usertype (something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940642/hibernate-postgres-array-type).

Answer (score 2):

So you have array of single characters... Problem is that in PG that is not fixed length. I had this problem, but around 10 years ago. At that time I had that column mapped as string, and that way I was able to process internal data - simply slice by comma, and do what is needed. 
If you hate that way, as I did... Look for columns with `text[]` type - that is more common, so it is quite easy to find out something. Please look at this sample project: 
https://github.com/phstudy/jpa-array-converter-sample